# How to increase the number of displayed thicks on the x-axis for predefined x-range?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Say, I have a plot with x axis described by `numpy.arange(-100, 1000, 1)`. The plot looks like this:

[image]

The problem is, I want x thicks to be for example every 100, or even 50. How can I achieve that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [The docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) are your friend.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is easier than I've thought. It can be eg.:

```
py.xticks(np.arange(-100, 1100, 100))
```

We'll get than:

[image]